# Why is explicit cast required with LINQ's First(), but not required in foreach?

Tags: c#

Can someone please explain how this piece of code works?

```
Action a = action;

Delegate[] alist = a.GetInvocationList();

// conversion between System.Delagate and System.Action is done
foreach(Action ac in alist) {
}

// cannot convert from System.Delagate to System.Action
Delegate firstDelegate = alist.First();
Action firstAction = firstDelegate; // compile error needs explicit cast
```

but... but how could it convert the Delegate to Action in the foreach statement if it needs and explicit cast as the compiled complained later??
is foreach using explicit casts behind the scenes??

Comment: *is foreach using explicit casts behind the scenes??* when used this way, yes. carry over from non generic times :)

Comment: @IvanStoev but how the compiler knows that the cast is possible?

Comment: Because `Action` is a delegate type.  So are `Func<T>`, `EventHandler` and  many others.

Comment: The selected duplicate is not ideal, because OP's question is about a specific comparison of the cast in `foreach` and a lack of cast in `First()`. In contrast, the duplicate is about C# not applying an available user-defined conversion inside `foreach`, which is not the same thing. I am voting to reopen this question.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight god bless you, wish was a way to bring back vote-ups though ;(

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Perhaps the question needs a more specific title then?  It seems to me that this question asks multiple questions, the foremost (based on title) being whether or not foreach requires an explicit cast (which the previously linked question already addresses).

Comment: @xDaevax I agree, changing the title makes perfect sense here. Thanks for a good suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How could it convert the Delegate to Action in the `foreach` statement if it needs and explicit cast as the compiled complained later?

Long story short, `foreach` statement adds an explicit cast on your behalf. This is done for compatibility with C# before generics have been introduced. The idea was to simplify iterations over untyped collections, e.g.

```
// Use an untyped list which stores System.Object objects
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);
list.Add(4);
list.Add(8);
foreach (int x in list) { // C# inserts a cast for you
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Because the cast is there in `foreach`, the code will compile, but it may break at run time. LINQ's `First()`, on the other hand, takes full advantage of static type checking, requiring you to specify an explicit cast.

Comment: if it is explicit, how come i can't convert Delegate to some other type like string or int??

Comment: you can put in foreach like ``foreach(string s in list)`` but it will fail on runtime and will throw invalidcastexception

Comment: @EhsanSajjad C# will prohibit this at compile time, in the same way that it would with an explicit cast ([demo](http://ideone.com/aehSvp)).

Comment: @MohsenShakiba ...Because delegates aren't of type string or int.

Comment: @MohsenShakiba C# will check if a cast is possible, both in `foreach` and in an explicit cast. In both cases you would get a compile-time error.